# Why does Module::Build's testcover gives me "use of uninitialized value" warnings?

Tags: perl, build, warnings, code-coverage

I'm kinda new to Module::Build, so maybe I did something wrong.  Am I the only one who gets warnings when I change my dispatch from "test" to "testcover"?  Is there a bug in Devel::Cover?   Is there a bug in Module::Build?  I probably just did something wrong.

I'm using ActiveState Perl v5.10.0 with Module::Build version 0.31012 and Devel::Cover 0.64 and Eclipse 3.4.1 with EPIC 0.6.34 for my IDE.

*UPDATE: I upgraded to Module::Build 0.34 and the warnings are still output.*

*UPDATE: Looks like a bug in B::Deparse.  Hope it gets fixed someday.*

Here's my unit test build file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Build;

my $build = Module::Build->resume (
  properties => {
    config_dir => '_build',
  },
);

$build->dispatch('test');
```

When I run this unit test build file, I get the following output:

```
t\MyLib1.......ok 
t\MyLib2.......ok 
t\MyLib3.......ok 
All tests successful. 
Files=3, Tests=24,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 cusr +  0.00 csys =  0.00 CPU)
```

But when I change the dispatch line to 'testcover' I get the following output which always includes a bunch of "use of uninitialized value in bitwise and" warning messages:

```
Deleting database D:/Documents and Settings/<username>/My Documents/<SNIP>/cover_db
t\MyLib1.......ok
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at D:/Perl/lib/B/Deparse.pm line 4252.
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at D:/Perl/lib/B/Deparse.pm line 4252.
t\MyLib2.......ok
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at D:/Perl/lib/B/Deparse.pm line 4252.
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at D:/Perl/lib/B/Deparse.pm line 4252.
t\MyLib3.......ok
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at D:/Perl/lib/B/Deparse.pm line 4252.
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at D:/Perl/lib/B/Deparse.pm line 4252.
All tests successful.
Files=3, Tests=24,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 cusr +  0.00 csys =  0.00 CPU)
Reading database from D:/Documents and Settings/<username>/My Documents/<SNIP>/cover_db

---------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
File                           stmt   bran   cond    sub    pod   time  total
---------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
.../lib/ActivePerl/Config.pm    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    n/a    0.0
...l/lib/ActiveState/Path.pm    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  100.0    n/a    4.8
<SNIP>
blib/lib/<SNIP>/MyLib2.pm     100.0   90.0    n/a  100.0  100.0    0.0   98.5
blib/lib/<SNIP>/MyLib3.pm     100.0   90.9  100.0  100.0  100.0    0.6   98.0
Total                          14.4    6.7    3.8   18.3   20.0  100.0   11.6
---------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------

Writing HTML output to D:/Documents and Settings/<username>/My Documents/<SNIP>/cover_db/coverage.html ...
done.
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug in `B::Deparse`.

Comment: I upgraded B::Deparse just now and the warning moved to a different line number, but it's pointing to the same call in that module as before.

Comment: I emailed the author of B::Deparse.  We'll have to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Line 4252 is:

```
$kid = $op->first;
if ( $kid->flags & OPf_SPECIAL # Line 4252
 and ( $] < 5.009 ? $kid->pmflags & PMf_SKIPWHITE()
      : $kid->reflags & RXf_SKIPWHITE() ) ) {
$exprs[0] = "' '";
}
```

so this seems to be related to `$kid->flags` not being defined for some reason.

What do you get if you do

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-d -e my_test_script
```

**Note:** I just checked the [repository version of B::Deparse](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/da18ba6f74b62ce1106538297a6945c01f1d33c1:/ext/B/B/Deparse.pm) and it is at version 0.89 whereas the version installed with my AS Perl 5.10 is version 0.83.

As temporary measure, can you backup `Deparse.pm` that came with AS Perl and replace it with the current version to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: `$kid` could be a no-op, I don't think those get flags. If it is it sounds like a minor bug.

Comment: @Brad thank you. I do not know much about internals but what you say makes sense.

Comment: I don't actually know that much, but I do know that the optimizer will leave behind no-ops.

Comment: Placed the new Deparse.pm file in and got the same errors.  The line number in the errors just moved to line 4295.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking me to do with that command line.  (remember, I use Eclipse Epic IDE, so I don't know command line stuff)  It appears to parse the name of my unit test build script when I perform that command line.

Comment: perl -MO=Deparse,-d -e Build1-UnitTests.pl [ENTER]
"Build1" - "UnitTests" . "pl"; [NEWLINE]
-e syntax OK

Answer (score 0):

The author of B::Deparse emailed me that he was able to reproduce the error with the following one-liner:

```
% perl -MO=Deparse -we '$r = qr/foo/; my @a = split($r, $_)' 
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
$r = qr/foo/;
Use of uninitialized value in bitwise and (&) at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/B/Deparse.pm line 4250.
my(@a) = split(/$r/, $_, 0);
-e syntax OK
```

Then he asked me to forward the bug to perlbug.  I do not know what he is talking about.  I hope this doesn't get dropped.  Do any of you Perl gurus who are reading this want to take this ball and run with it?

Comment: perlbug is http://bugs.perl.org/. The bug is fixed: http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=71870